# Android collapsing toolbar smooth scroll is not happening

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I have added collapsing tool bar inside drawerlayout, everything is fine but when i scroll up it's not smooth. i have added all attributes which are needed for collapsing tool bar to work fine but when i scrolling up it's lagging.

below is my xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/dp250"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />

            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigationView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        app:menu="@menu/nav_menu" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Now I got whats the problem. You are using **NestedScrollView**
Replace it with **RecyclerView** And
Change `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"` from above code to

```
app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlwaysCollapsed|snap|exitUntilCollapsed"
```

Let me know if that worked!

Comment: same issue still not scrolling smooth

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
```

To this

```
app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
```

In collapsing toolbar and remove

```
app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
```

From toolbar tag and view tag

Comment: still same issue,not scrolling smooth\

Comment: Why have u added framelayout in nested scrollview?